# Runtime Error 3075 when running SQL query for a search form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to code a text box search system but am getting Runtime Error 3075.

The recordsource for the form is a SQL statement from a query
that I used. The same SQL statement is in the code below and I added `WHERE` and `OR`.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT Products.ProdID, categories.CatName, Makes.MakeName, Products.ProdModel, Products.ProdDesc, Suppliers.SuppName, ProdType.TypeName, Colours.ColName, Size.SizeName, Products.DateAdded, Products.ProdBarcode" _
     & "FROM Suppliers RIGHT JOIN (categories RIGHT JOIN (ProdType RIGHT JOIN (Makes RIGHT JOIN ((Colours RIGHT JOIN Products ON Colours.ColourID = Products.ColourID) LEFT JOIN [Size] ON Products.SizeID = Size.SizeID) ON Makes.MakeID = Products.ProdMake) ON ProdType.TypeID = Products.ProdTypeID) ON categories.CatID = Products.ProdCategory) ON Suppliers.SuppID = Products.SupplierID" _
     & "WHERE (((Products.ProdModel) Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*'))" _
     & "Or (((Products.ProdBarcode) Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*'))" _
     & "ORDER BY categories.CatName;"

 Me.Form.RecordSource = SQL
End Sub
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add spaces in between your lines, or the words just run together...

Comment: You can debug SQL yourself in Access, copy the generated SQL to the query editor and let Access help you.

Comment: Like Tim said: SQL holds "SELECT ....., Products.ProdBarcodeFROM Suppliers RIGHT JOIN ...
It should hold ""SELECT ....., Products.ProdBarcode FROM Suppliers RIGHT JOIN ...  (and the same on each line break)

Comment: Hello Tim, Nathan and Harassed Dad. Thank you very much for your quick reply. But sorry I do not understand what you mean by spaces in between my lines.

Comment: What Tim and "Dad" are say is that you need a space at the beginning of each line. Read the contribution by Harassed Dad again, very carefully. Pay attention to `FROM` and how it looks with the text preceding. The beginning of each line needs this: `& " FROM` - a space between the `"` and the SQL term.

Comment: Instead of building a complete SQL statement, could set Filter and FilterOn properties of form instead. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Ok great now I get it. Thank you very much guys. I'll try this out in the morning

Comment: It worked! Thank you guys for explaining it to me.